# JPanel not showing

Tags: java, swing

I need to have an interface ready and with clickable buttons to show all the different windows we have created so far.

Now a teammember of mine has created multiple JFrames for each window we want the user to work with. We're all working in the NetBeans IDE. I'm trying to get a login window to popup and from there on i will be making all the windows show up when a button is clicked which should direct the user to that window.

Here is what we have so far:
(Main)

```
     import java.awt.*;
     import javax.swing.*;

    public class Corendon {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
           showLogin();
    }

    private static void showLogin(){
        Login login = new Login();

        login.setVisible(true);
        login.validate();
    }
}
```

The code in Login.java as requested by a user:

```
/*
* To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/

/**
*
* @author Daan
*/
public class Login extends javax.swing.JPanel {

/**
 * Creates new form Login
 */
public Login() {
    initComponents();
}

/**
 * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
 * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
 * regenerated by the Form Editor.
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
private void initComponents() {

    jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
    jPasswordField1 = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
    jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
    jComboBox1 = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
    jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
    jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();

    jLabel1.setIcon(new    javax.swing.ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Daan\\Dropbox\\HvA\\Programming\\Corendon\\corendon.png")); // NOI18N

    jLabel2.setText("Username");

    jLabel3.setText("Password");

    jComboBox1.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Dutch", "English" }));

    jButton1.setText("Login");
    jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
        }
    });

    jButton2.setText("Cancel");

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(31, 31, 31)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1))
                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addGap(45, 45, 45)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addComponent(jLabel3)
                        .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGap(14, 14, 14)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                            .addComponent(jButton2)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(jButton1))
                        .addComponent(jPasswordField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 214, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 214, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
            .addContainerGap(22, Short.MAX_VALUE))
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap(16, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addGap(18, 18, 18)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jPasswordField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jLabel3))
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                .addComponent(jComboBox1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addComponent(jButton1))
            .addGap(35, 35, 35))
    );
}// </editor-fold>                        

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                        

// Variables declaration - do not modify                     
private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
private javax.swing.JComboBox jComboBox1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
private javax.swing.JPasswordField jPasswordField1;
private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
// End of variables declaration                   


}
```

As you can see i'm trying to get the Login window to showup when the user runs the program. But what i'm currently dealing with is the fact that if i set the setVisible parameter to true, it doesn't actually show up. The program will in fact just run for 1 second and than stop.

Is there anything i'm doing wrong here? Also in each of the classes we have not yet created any event handlers. They are only windows with multiple components on them.

Comment: Show code here. Not from imgur.

Comment: can you please share code of Login class.

Comment: A side note. You may want to look into `JOptionPane` and `JDialog` (if you already covered them). [This tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`JPanel` needs to be wrapped inside a `Window` component such as a `JFrame` to show up.

Replace your `showLogin` Method with the following:

```
Login login = new Login();

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.add(login);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```